# Emphasis on "however"

Tags: sentence, emphasis

I would like to know that in which position (front, middle, end) the term "however" sounds more emphatic.

**Example:**

1. England lost the match. However, they can win the the tournament if they do well in the upcoming match.
2. England lost the match. They can, however, win the the tournament if they do well in the upcoming match.
3. England lost the match. They can win the the tournament if they do well in the upcoming match, however.

Which one of the above sentences is more emphatic?

Comment: I would say #2 puts more emphasis on the *concept* of "however".  Other options may cause the word to be pronounced louder, but that's rarely the point.

Answer (score 2):

Example 1 emphasizes "however" the most. In that sentence, the world "however" carries the stress, and frames the rest of the sentence.

Example 2 puts the emphasis on the word "can."

Example 3 de-emphasizes "however."